# Logstash-Logback Encoder: “IllegalAccessError: failed to access class […]”

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I try to send logs from a java application with the Logstash tcp socket appender to logstash. The java app. already works with logback 1.1.9 (slf4j) and other appenders.

Now I added the following lines to the logback-test.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="logstash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>[IP]:5010</destination>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <fieldNames>
                <message>log_msg</message>
            </fieldNames>
        </encoder>
        <keepAliveDuration>5 minutes</keepAliveDuration>
    </appender>

<root>
<level value="info"/>
<appender-ref ref="logstash" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

But when I add the appender and start my java application, I get an error from the JVM Launcher "A Java Exception has occured" and I get the following console text:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnPrintStreamStatusListenerBase from class net.logstash.logback.status.LevelFilteringStatusListener (ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnPrintStreamStatusListenerBase and net.logstash.logback.status.LevelFilteringStatusListener are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at net.logstash.logback.status.LevelFilteringStatusListener.setDelegate(LevelFilteringStatusListener.java:67)
    at net.logstash.logback.appender.AsyncDisruptorAppender.start(AsyncDisruptorAppender.java:370)
    at net.logstash.logback.appender.AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender.start(AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender.java:1009)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:90)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:158)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:145)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:103)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
```

I included the logstash 6.3 jar-file and because of this error, I also tried it with an older version, 4.9. Does anybody know if that is compatible to logback 1.1.9?
I'm not using Spring-Boot.

---------Edit 17.02.2020-----------

My input of the logstash.conf file (because I don't get any log from my java application):

```
input {
   tcp {
      mode => "server"
      port => 5010
      codec => json
   }
}
```

Comment: When I remove the <encoder>, I don't get this error and the application is running. But I need a working encoder^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

I updated logback from 1.1.9 to 1.2.3. As I replaced the jar files and addeded them to the class-path, I got over 600 times the following error-message: `Logger cannot be resolved to a type`. I fixed this by opening the properties in Eclipse from the logback project, going on "Order and Export" and setting a marker in every checkbox --> Apply and close. Now I don't get the IllegalAccessError any more and my java application is running fine. And I also now can see the logs in Logstash and Kibana :)

I downloaded the following files:

- jcl-over-slf4j 1.7.25
- jul-to-slf4j 1.7.25
- log4j-over-slf4j 1.7.25
- slf4j-api 1.7.25
- logback-classic 1.2.3
- logback-core 1.2.3

I downloaded them from here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the exception you encountered by applying any of the following solutions:

A) Use logback version >= 1.1.10

OR

B) Add `<addDefaultStatusListener>false</addDefaultStatusListener>` to your appender definition (see details [here](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/blob/2e98d6c74d3e19bfd6780dfe593e8b020ed7d10e/README.md#status-listeners))

OR

C) Add a [status listener](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#dumpingStatusData) to your logback configuration (which prevents logstash-logback-encoder from adding a default status listener).

The exception occurs because logstash-logback-encoder versions >= 6.0 reference logback's `ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnPrintStreamStatusListenerBase` class when adding a [default status listener](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/blob/2e98d6c74d3e19bfd6780dfe593e8b020ed7d10e/README.md#status-listeners).  `OnPrintStreamStatusListenerBase` was made public in logback 1.1.10, and was package-private before then.

Applying any of the above solutions will avoid the exception you encountered.  However, keep in mind that logstash-logback-encoder versions >= 4.8 are compiled and tested against logback 1.2.x.  Therefore, you might encounter other errors when using logback 1.1.x.  The logstash-logback-encoder readme contains the following statement on this topic:

> Older versions than the ones specified in the pom file might work, but the versions in the pom file are what testing has been performed against.

Comment: Thank you very much!

I tried option B) and it works, my java app is running. But I don't get any log in Logstash or Kibana. Logstash was working, I used it with filebeat before. 

I also tested the logstash-encoder version 4.8 because it works with logback 1.1.2 (I have 1.1.9) and since LS-encoder 4.9, I need logback 1.2.1. But without adding the line in B) from your answer, I get the same error. 
To update logback is not easy, I get 649 errors :/

Could it be that I don't get logs in Logstash because I added the line from B)?

I add my logstash config to my question.

Comment: Use the `json_lines` logstash codec (instead of `json`).  Also turn on logback debugging by starting your logback file with `<configuration debug="true">` to see if it shows to any problems.  The configuration from B) will not prevent logs from being sent to logstash.

Comment: I now updated logback from 1.1.9 to 1.2.3. I fixed the error "Logger cannot be resolved" by setting hooks to all boxes at "Order and Export" (Properties --> Java Build Path). 
Now it works without the line`<addDefaultStatusListener>false</addDefaultStatusListener>` . Now I get the following error:
`-WARN in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[logstash] - Log destination [ip]:5010: connection failed. java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`
When I listen on the port, I see that the VM is receiving data when I start my java app. But there is no response.